# how to make one iteration per clock edge unlike all iterations in one clock edge

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, verilog

the for loop in the following code is begin executed in one posedge clock.i want each iteration to occur at one clock edge so that at 5th clock edge my if will be activated.

```
begin 
  temp_number3=contact;
    for(i3=0;i3<10;i3=i3+1)
     begin //for loop beign 
     count3=i3;
     if(count3==5)
        begin //beign for if 
        message=1;
         contact_num=temp_number3; 
        end// end for if 
    end // end of for loop 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `for-loop`, but an always block that is active on `posedge` of clock, i.e.:

```
begin
    always@(posedge clk)
    begin
       if(count3 == 5) begin
          message <= 1;
          contact_num <= temp_number3;
          count3 <= count3 + 1;
       end else if(count 3 == 9) begin
          count3 <= 0;
          stopFlag <= 1;
       end else if(~stopFlag)
          count3 <= count3 + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: i want this loop to stop after 10 clock cycles ?so how can that happen

Comment: @rohithveligeti: i've edited example a little bit. I hope now you can see how to do it.